# Port 22 is always open

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, ufw

I configured a new Ubuntu Installation and set up the firewall. All incoming was denied and all outgoing was denied as well(with exception for port 8080, as I am behind a proxy). I then tried an online port scan and found that my ssh port(22) was open. I double checked but the problem remained. I specifically denied port 22 in the firewall, but the port is still shown as open(all other ports are closed). What is the reason behind this?

Output of `netstat -tlpn` is

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Please add the output of `netstat -tlpn` to your question..

Comment: I wouldn't trust online scanners much. Use `nmap`

Comment: As you can see port 22 is not in listening state i.e. open..

Comment: If you are using an online scanner you are scanning your router.

Comment: Does that mean that my firewall(configured locally) isn't being scanned at all? The "router's"(the proxy servers, I suppose in this case, run by the college) capabilities are tested by the scans?   That does make sense though, since I am getting the same results with firewall disabled as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `netstat -tlpn` output indicates you don't have port 22 is in `LISTEN` state that is the port is closed.

As for the Online scan results, this should be the results from scanning the public IP interface of your router (could be the proxy in your case).

Comment: In the netstat output, one of the items displayed is "127.0.0.1:631 ". The first part 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address; what does the second part(631) mean? Is it that port 631 is listening for traffic?

Comment: @MayankSingh Yes..its the IPP (Internet Printing Protocol)..btw don't disable port 53 by any means, its the DNS port..

Comment: On my home internet connection(mobile broadband directly connected the the internet), I had to manually allow all the required ports for outbound connection(80,443,53 at the least) so as to get online.   Whilst, in college, while I am behind proxy,  I only allowed 8080 to communicate online(which is the proxy port behind http). How then is port 53 automatically listening when it isn't allowed by the firewall?Shouldn't it be like manually allowed in the firewall before it can be in listen mode?

Comment: @MayankSingh Hold on..you have port 53 is in listening state..whats the output of `sudo netstat -tlpn | grep -Po '^tcp\s.*:53\s+.*LISTEN\s+\K[^\s]+'` ?

Comment: The output comes out to "3341/dnsmasq" though I don't understand what it means.

Comment: @MayankSingh Ahh..makes sense..by default Ubuntu uses `dnsmasq`-a lightweight dns server mainly used for caching..read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59424/68757)